# Retrofit - uploading an image

Tags: android, post, retrofit, image-uploading

I am having trouble uploading an image with retrofit.

My retrofit service interface:

```
@Multipart
@Headers({
        "Content-Type: application/json"
})
@POST("upload_photo")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadPhoto(@Part MultipartBody.Part filePart);
```

Calling the service:

```
MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("photo", fileName, RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), bitmapByteArray));
Call<ResponseBody> call = service.uploadPhoto(filePart);
```

The problem is that the webservice does not find a part with a key/name `photo` and returns that the sent image is NULL.

[This is the call on postman that works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3B3E.png)

Comment: remove content type from header and then try

Comment: @Nik thank you.. That was it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
@Multipart
@POST("upload_photo")
Observable<ResponseBody> uploadPhoto(@Part("photo") RequestBody photo);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//pass it like this
File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/Corrections 6.jpg");
RequestBody requestFile =
        RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

// MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
MultipartBody.Part body =
        MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), requestFile);

service.uploadPhoto(body);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   @Multipart
@POST("upload_image")
Call<UserProfileResponseBean> upload_image(@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> part);



if (path.isEmpty()) {
            upload_image = servicesInterface.upload_image(map);
        } else {
            File imagepath = new File(path);
            MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", imagepath.getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), imagepath));
            upload_image = servicesInterface.upload_image(map, body);
        }
```